# Add Patient to Physician model if not already has an Appointment in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Consider the following models:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

**Objective**:

1. Create a Patient if not already exists.
2. Add Patient to particular physician, if not already exists

I thought, I could do this two ways:

**Method 1**

```
physician = Physician.find(physician_id)
unless Patient.where(email: email).empty?
  record = physician.patients.create email: email
else
#Patient already exist, just add them to appointment
  record = Patient.where(email: email)
  physician.patients << record
end
```

**Method 2**

```
physician = Physician.find(physician_id)
record = Patient.find_or_create_by(email: email)
# avoid overhead of SQL JOINS, use simple SELECT/CREATE
if Appointment.where(physician_id: physician_id).where(patient_id: record.id).empty?
   Appointment.create physician_id: physician.id, patient_id: record.id
end
```

Now,
which is the better way out of the above two? Also, is there another way which is better than than above term in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about option 3:

```
physician = Physician.find(physician_id)
unless physician.patients.where(email: email).exists?
  patient = Patient.find_or_create_by(email: email)
  physician.appointments.create(patient: patient)
end
```

If the patient already has an appointment with this physician, this will avoid the unnecessary call to `find_or_create_by`.

And for the record, calling `model.association.create(...)` won't perform *any* joins.  It works on an ActiveRelation object representing the association, and will just trigger an INSERT statement.  However, there are several other technical problems with your suggested method 1, and your method 2 is needlessly verbose.

Comment: Can you list what are the "several other technical problems" with d method 1? Because I have used this same idiom in other places of my codebase

Comment: @GaurishSharma: Firstly, `unless Patient.where(email: email).empty?` is the reverse case of what you are looking for.  Secondly, you aren't testing for the case where the patient already has an appointment with this physician.  And lastly, while you can create and assign through the `physicians.patients` relationship, you are limited to those attributes alone, and can't set any details on the appointment object.  Using the interim appointment association, you have much more control over the assignment.